# Pandas: Multiindex dataframe indexing - set values to dataframe subset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Multiindex dataframe with 2 index levels and 2 column levels.

The first level index and first index columns are the same. The second levels share elements but are not equal. This gives me a non square dataframe (I have more elements in my 2nd level columns than in my second level index)

I want to set all elements of my dataframe to 0 in the case the first level index is not equal to the first level column. I have done it recursively but am sure there is a better way.

Can you help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a sample dataframe and expected results to this question.

Comment: Update your question. Please   thanks.

Comment: Sure.

Taking the example from pydata website

arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 6), index=index[:6], columns=index[:6])

I want all elements of the dataframe for which first level column and first level index are not the same set to 0 (i.e. bar/baz, bar/foo, baz/bar, baz/foo, foo/bar, foo/baz)

Comment: Apologies, I realize this is still non specific. I have found a way to do it but it still looks rather ugly:

for index in level1_index:
            df.loc[index,list(set(level1_column).difference(set([index])))]=0